# iText me crea el PDF, lo abre, pero no me imprime nada

Tags: java, itextsharp, itext

Estoy aprendiendo actualmente iText, ya que mi trabajo me lo exige. Parto de la base de que mis conocimientos en Java no son nulos, pero tampoco son avanzados.

Así que, decidí cogerme el ecuatorial de la web de iText y empezar a aplicar los tutoriales que tiene. Y mi primer error lo encuentro en el capitulo 1 (os pongo el código de NetBeans). 
El caso es que copio y pego el texto tal cual y NetBeans empieza a darme errores. Entre ellos el que tengo que añadir una función (`try`, `catch`) para poder escribir el código.

Lo pongo "automáticamente" y el resultado es un PDF generado, pero que no me pinta ni párrafo ni nada.

Si me pueden ayudar estaría agradecida.

```
    /*
 * This example is part of the iText 7 tutorial.
 */
package tutorial.chapter01.eva;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.test.annotations.WrapToTest;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Simple Hello World example.
 */
@WrapToTest
public class C01E01_HelloWorld {

    public static final String DEST = "results/chapter01/hello_world25.pdf";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new C01E01_HelloWorld().createPdf(DEST);
    }

    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
        //Initialize PDF writer
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);

        //Initialize PDF document
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

        try ( // Initialize document
            Document document = new Document(pdf)) {
            //Add paragraph to the document
            document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
            //Close document
        }
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: por cierto el ejercicio lo pueden encontrar aquí :https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples/chapter-1

Comment: Puedes poner los errores que esta arrojando Netbeans

Comment: ¿es un proyecto Maven?

Comment: @LuisFernando son tantos que no se como hacerlos llegar.

Comment: @AlvaroC. hola alvaro, bajo mi ignorancia creo que no lo es. ¿Por que? Hay diferencias?

Comment: Hola! He conseguido simplificar el código de forma que ya por fín me crea el pdf. Pongo el nuevo. Gracias.

Comment: @AlvaroC.Si efectivamente creo que es un proyecto maven

Comment: Perfecto ya lo he solucionado. Me faltaba añadir la libreía slf4j y el código logger muchas grácias por vuestro interés

Comment: @EvaMV, por favor, [publica y acepta tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.